# Library dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way to have library dependencies in Android Studio as conveniently as in Eclipse?

I have two libraries, the second one depends on the first one, and an app which depends on both libraries.
In Eclipse I had all the projects in one workspace and the dependencies defined. When a change was made in one library, that change was immediately available in the app's project.

In Android Studio, I included the generated aar files of the libraries in the app's project, which created a copy of the aar file in the app's project. When I make a change in a library, I have to regenerate the aar file and copy it to the correct folder of the app project.

There has to be a better way, right?

Comment: You probably want to learn about remote dependencies. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

Comment: @qki: Thanks for the link. As I understand it, there are three types of dependencies: local library module, local binary and remote binary. I currently use local library module. Therefore the library has to be a module in the app project. To have this, I only found two ways: import the library code (which copies the source code) or import the aar file which results in the described problem.